# Flutter: Unable to pass Detection Type for count detection, how to pass all 3 types in initPlatformState?

Tags: flutter, types, count, tags, detection

Unable to pass the Detection Type for the handheld device.In our code we do initPlatformState with the following code

```
 Future<void> initPlatformState(DetectionType type) async {
    ///set the power level
    var powerLevel = 10;
    if (type == DetectionType.closeDetection) {
      powerLevel = 10;
    } else if (type == DetectionType.wideDetection) {
      powerLevel = 20;
    } else if (type == DetectionType.maxDetection) {
      powerLevel = 30;
    }
    logger.d(powerLevel);
    await UhfC72Plugin.stop();
    UhfC72Plugin.tagStream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(updateTags);
    await UhfC72Plugin.connect();
    await UhfC72Plugin.setPower(powerLevel);
    print('Initialisation done');
  }
```

in the scan mode form we cant able to pass DetectionType that means we have 3 types of detection in initPlatformState but in the code of the above form we have only one option so i hard code as

```
context
                                  .read<AnimalsCubit>()
                                  .initPlatformState(
                                      DetectionType.maxDetection);
```

instead of hardcode one type to another how to add all 3 types anyone please suggest ?

i tried manually as follows

```
context
                                  .read<AnimalsCubit>()
                                  .initPlatformState(
                                      DetectionType.maxDetection);
```